# Manage debian servers packages with Foreman

Tags: debian, package-management, foreman, katello

Is there some way how i can manage packages in debian using foreman, for example when new updates are available it will tell me and i have to approve it first before installing... 
i checked Katello but that is just for Red hat and fedora...or pulp... i would also like to have some dashboard (ideally in foreman), i chcecked apt-dater but it works only in terminal...
Or is there some good puppet module i could use?
I am managing around 100 servers

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but our solution was to have a dedicated apt mirror that syncs monthly.  We then configure our clients to point to the internal mirror and have critical services pinned in our puppet manifests to either latest or specific versions.